# How to add or remove a single element from/to CellList?

Tags: java, gwt

How to add/remove a single element to/from [`CellList`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.html) ?

Comment: Do you mean Element? http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Element.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a `ListDataProvider<T>` get the wrapped list and simply add or remove an element.

A really simple example:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final ListDataProvider<String> provider = new ListDataProvider<String>(getList());
    CellList<String> list = new CellList<String>(new TextCell());
    provider.addDataDisplay(list);

    Button btn = new Button("add more");
    btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        private int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            provider.getList().add(++counter + " more");
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(list);
    RootPanel.get().add(btn);
}

private LinkedList<String> getList() {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    list.add("1st");
    list.add("2nd");
    list.add("3rd");
    list.add("4th");
    list.add("5th");
    return list;
}
```